# Why does the parent element have a bigger height when child element have a smaller font-size?

Tags: html, css

In html css , I noticed this weird behavior: the smaller is the font-size of a child element, the bigger is the height of the parent element , even with a given line-height .

https://jsfiddle.net/a4zjroyn/

Example : when a child element has a font-size of 12px , the parent element have a height of 21px by line

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        .city-parent {
            line-height: 20px;
        }
        .city {
            font-size: 12px; 
            line-height: 20px;
        }
    </style>
    <title>exemple font size height</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="city-parent">
        <span class="city">City of a country with a quite long name</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: font size 12px on 2 lines]
[image: font size 12px on 1 line]

When a child element has a font-size of 6px , the parent element have a bigger height : an height of 23.3px by line

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            .city-parent {
                line-height: 20px;
            }
            .city {
                font-size: 6px; 
                line-height: 20px;
            }
        </style>
        <title>exemple font size height</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="city-parent">
            <span class="city">City of a country with a quite long name</span>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I notice that if the parent line is in display : flex , then the height has a 20px height.

[image: font size 6px on 1 line]

[image]

Could you explain why it happens please?
And optionaly  say if you could have a solution for having  20px for the parent's height without using a display : flex

Comment: Interesting, on Firefox the parent has a height of `n * 20px` regardless of the font-size

Comment: thank you for the answere @JensV ,  on firefox , the parent has NOT an height of n * 20px regardless of the font-size

Comment: Actually, I'm getting the same result on chromium as well... Maybe the font plays a role here? I'm running on Gnome with `Liberation Serif` as my default font

Comment: How weird... I can reproduce it here: https://jsfiddle.net/sqfkbacp/

Comment: Note that the doctype matters here. Your missing doctype on your first example affects the behaviour.

Comment: Please don't tag your titles. See [ask].